# What happens when an SQL entry contains SQL code?

Tags: sql-server

I've done some searching and can't seem to find an answer anywhere.
What can happen (if anything) if an entry in an SQL DB contains actual SQL code?

I've just found that an internal application at work (SQL based) can insert anything into a table including code. The datatype of the columns with this ability is Varchar.

Is there any risk with this ability, and what/how can this be a bad thing?

Comment: I wont see this as a risk. But why are you storing `SQL` code in table. If you plan to execute the stored `SQL` codes, then it will be become  difficult job.

Comment: I'm not actually trying to store any code in a table, but have noticed that it's possible to do so. I'm concerned that it could be a risk. Can code inside a table be executed at all?

Comment: It is not a big deal to store `SQL` codes inside a table. It will be just stored as string just like any other string

Comment: And yes you can execute the `SQL` codes inside the tables by assigning the `SQL` codes to a variable and execute it using `EXEC` or `SP_EXECUTESQL`

Comment: So the application itself needs to specifically execute any contained code? It can't be forced (I'm trying to compare this to SQL injection) via field input?

Comment: No, it can't be forced, it would always be treated as any other string. Use parametrized queries to prevent SQL injection and you are safe.